# How to save captured image path from imageview to mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, database

I was wondering if someone could help me I'm creating form on android and the user has to insert an image. The application opens up the camera, the user can take a picture and that image is set to an imageview. My question is how to I get the image path of the imageview to save it mysql database using php.

```
private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                filePath = getPath(fileUri);

                final Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);

                image1.setImageBitmap(image);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No picture for your Schedule", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        }
        }
```

Comment: Save the image path in String variable when you select image and use it whenever you need.

Comment: what's your "filePath = getPath(fileUri)" do?

Comment: its meant to get the filepath of the image that has just been captured by getting the path of the file uri

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting imagepath fom captured image set to imageview and save to database by getting imagview path value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747492/getting-imagepath-fom-captured-image-set-to-imageview-and-save-to-database-by-ge)

Comment: i am extending the BaseAdapter for Listview in that what should be the code for onActivityResult() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i think you already have what you need. When you use:

```
filePath = getPath(fileUri);
```

There you have the Uri, and the Path. Now with that info, you should make an HttpPost to your savePath.php file in your server. You must make the request inside an AsyncTask.

http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient

Comment: how would get the imageview path? so if i was to get the imageview value and then store than path value in the database using Httpost?

Comment: when you put the image in the imageview, you have the uri and the path

Comment: i am extending the BaseAdapter for Listview in that what should be the code for onActivityResult() method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use java to add the path to a mysql database...

insert this into your code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

Connection conn = null;
try {  
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
}catch (Exception exe) { 
  System.err.println("Unable to load driver."); 
  exe.printStackTrace();
  toReturn += "Unable to load driver."; 
} 
try {  
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://"+hostname+"/"+dbname; 
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); 
  st = conn.createStatement();
}catch (SQLException sqle) { 
  System.out.println("SQLException: " + sqle.getMessage()); 
  System.out.println("SQLState: " + sqle.getSQLState()); 
  System.out.println("VendorError: " + sqle.getErrorCode()); 
  sqle.printStackTrace();
  toReturn += "Can't connect to the Server. Check Username/Password.";
}
try{
    st.execute("insert into \tablename\ values(\""+filePath+"\")");
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
try {
  conn.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```